# cryptocompare module in Anaconda not installed to get real time cryptocurrencies price

Tags: python, anaconda, cryptocurrency

Ni Hao,
I am trying to read cryptocurrencies price in python. I tried to install cryptocompare module, but using the following codes in Anaconda prompt did not work:

```
 conda install cryptocompare

 conda install -c conda-forge cryptocompare
```

Also, I tried to install the downloaded file, but again did not work. Should I use another channel? If so, how can I add that channel. Also, if masters think better modules exist I appreciate to know that. Thanks

[image]

Comment: `didn't work` isn't an error message or problem description

Comment: Please [edit] to show the output of those commands and any other error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with pip

```
pip install cryptocompare
```